# How many hedge funds are there?

Tags: finance, investment

For personal interest. This 2022 [special report](https://issuu.com/globalfundmedia/docs/cayman_islands_in_focus_2022?fr=sYTllYTQ4MDcxNzU) on [hedgeweek.com](https://www.hedgeweek.com/special/cayman-islands-focus-2022) says,

> Cayman is domicile to over 23,000 CIVs, including about 80% of all international hedge funds

which suggests a maximum global figure of about 28,750; but so far my internet searches haven't turned up any clear statement on this.

I originally posted this question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/151456/how-many-hedge-funds-are-there) on the money stack, but they seem not to like it.

Comment: Can you please provide an exact definition of "hedge fund", since it is not a legal term?

Comment: @Giskard The most precise definition I've seen is "Hedge Funds as defined for the NBFI Monitoring Project are funds with a gross leverage ratio (GNE/NAV) exceeding 125%" https://www.cima.ky/upimages/publicationdoc/InvestmentsStatisti_1615563453.pdf